# Reportbuilder result from expression needs parenthesis

Tags: reporting-services, vbscript, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I wrote an expression in a report that checks for the translation in a database table. Both 'Lookup' statements give me a proper result: Result Actual. Now I want that the result of the second 'Lookup' statement comes between parenthesis but I can't seem to figure out where I should put extra parenthesis in my statement. Beneath is the expression I wrote. Can someone add some parenthesis? 
What I want to see is Result (Actual). Thanks in advance

```
    =Lookup("WDS_GEN_RESULT", Fields!LST_Id.Value, Fields!LST_Translation.Value, "LocalizedStringTranslations") 
& Lookup("WDS_GEN_ACTUAL", Fields!LST_Id.Value, Fields!LST_Translation.Value, "LocalizedStringTranslations")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    =Lookup("WDS_GEN_RESULT", Fields!LST_Id.Value, Fields!LST_Translation.Value, "LocalizedStringTranslations") & "(" &  
Lookup("WDS_GEN_ACTUAL", Fields!LST_Id.Value, Fields!LST_Translation.Value, "LocalizedStringTranslations") & ")"
```

So I've fixed this issue myself after a lot of trial and error. Above is the very simple code I used.